# Таблица Unicode или ASCII

Tags: сеть, доступ

Вот есть код подскажите в какой таблице он написан? Мне нужно узнать какое там слово за шифрованно. Какую можно использовать программу для расшифровки символов?25F57E2C07D53983F0F205D72997E779EA6890726D147B23736D3A49772D5657

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то это больше напоминает md5 хэш-сумму... Погуглите на тему "расшифровка хэш-сумм".